# Gitlab: commenting on full file rather than on diff?

Tags: git, gitlab

My understanding is that gitlab allows to comment on code only in the context of:

- merge requests
- when looking at commits
  In both case we can only comment on diffs between two commits.

Things are developed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559719/how-to-set-up-a-code-review-using-gitlab).

This makes total sense in the context of continuous integration. Yet, on some occasion I would find extremely useful to comment on the full code of one commit, independently to its diffs with other commit. My understanding is this is not possible on gitlab, but I may be wrong ?

ps: I have enterprise edition, in case that changes anything.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this currently isn't possible.

The desired functionality is tracked in [Code review on any line on any file in a merge request](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/19).

The issue dates back to Oct 8, 2018.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to comment on a commit, not a particular file or diff line. This is a feature on [GitHub](https://github.com/) and [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash) so it totally make sense. Luckily, there is this feature also on GitLab.

For example, open [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/a81ce718c772672706da33848670149dd577ae79) commit's page from gitlab-ce repository. If you are logged in, you'll see comment box at the bottom of the page. Also you'll see comment icons when you hover the code lines in the diff boxes.

Comment: My post was not so clear ... I want to be able to comment on any part of the file, whether or not it has modifications relative to another commit. In the link you provide, only the modified parts of the file are displayed. I can see the whole file by clicking on "view file" on the right, but then I can not comment anymore.

Comment: Ahh, I see your point now. Even if it seems a good feature, I guess there's no actual use in version control for that. So, sadly, GitLab doesn't have that functionality, also GitHub and Stash don't have it as well.

Comment: I suppose a "no, it can't be done as of now" it's an answer as well

Comment: No use? what about writing a comment on a line which references a variable which name was updated in some other part of the commit but was omitted here and still references a valid name?